# how to open xlsx file with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, xlrd

I have an xlsx file with 1 sheet.
I am trying to open it using python 3 (xlrd lib), but I get an empty file!

I use this code:

```
file_errors_location = "C:\\Users\\atheelm\\Documents\\python excel mission\\errors1.xlsx"
workbook_errors = xlrd.open_workbook(file_errors_location)
```

and I have no errors, but when I type:

```
workbook_errors.nsheets
```

I get "0", even the file has some sheets... when I type:

```
workbook_errors
```

I get:

```
xlrd.book.Book object at 0x2..
```

any help? thanks

Comment: What happens when you call 'workbook_errors.sheets()' and then 'workbook_errors.nsheets'?

Answer (score 37):

You can use Pandas `pandas.read_excel` just like `pandas.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
file_errors_location = 'C:\\Users\\atheelm\\Documents\\python excel mission\\errors1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_errors_location)
print(df)
```

Comment: Note that you need to have the library `xlrd` installed for this to work.

Comment: @gieldops is right. You can install `xlrd` with `pip install xlrd`

Comment: vary elegant! you can iterate over the rows using: `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Answer (score 19):

There are two modules for reading xls file : openpyxl and xlrd

This script allow you to transform a excel data to list of dictionnaries using xlrd

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\atheelm\\Documents\\python excel mission\\errors1.xlsx')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\atheelm\\Documents\\python excel mission\\errors1.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# tronsform the workbook to a list of dictionnary
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)
print data
```

Comment: when I type: "worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)"
I get the error: "list index out of range...."
because if I type worksheet .nsheets , I get 0 !!

Comment: no... I tried now to open a new file, it worked well.. it seems the file is locked or somthing

Comment: not sure.. because I still need to open that "locked" file.

Comment: The rows are indexed starting at zero, according to the documentation. You are missing the first row.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, the python engine 'xlrd' that is required to read the Excel docs has explicitly removed support for anything other than xls files.

So here's how you can do it now -

- Install openpyxl:

  https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- Change your pandas code to:

  `pandas.read_excel('cat.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')`

Note: This worked for me with the latest version of Pandas (i.e. 1.1.5). Previously, I was using version 0.24.0 and it didn't work so I had to update to latest version.

Comment: Just used pandas version 1.3.2, it asked me for dependency of `openpyxl`, installed it and `pandas.read_excel` worked without specifying `engine` parameter

Comment: @FlorentRoques when you do not explicitly specify the engine parameter, it defaults to None. In such case, there is a series of logic that determines the most appropriate engine for your document. Please check this link for more details - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it:

```
import openpyxl 
workbook_errors = openpyxl.Workbook()
workbook_errors = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_errors_location)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to use **openpyxl** due to:

- have openpyxl running super slow;
- find openpyxl too complicated;
- just want to load a worksheet as a dataframe;

**xlwings** is recommended (install by **pip install xlwings**), below is a sample:

```py
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

wb_path = ".\\***.xlsx" # the .xlsx file is in the same directory as the .py script
ws_name = "***" # the name of the worksheet to load data

wb = xw.Book(wb_path)
ws = wb.sheets[ws_name]

MAX_ROW = 100 # the rows to read, this can be larger, the empty rows can be dropped in Pandas dataframe
MAX_COL = 40 # the columns to read

data = ws[:MAX_ROW,:MAX_COL].value
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

By above codes, the worksheet can be loaded into a Pandas dataframe way faster than **openpyxl** does.