# xlwt: how to get row data of specific sheet?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I can iterate rows of sheet like:

```
for row_id in sheet.rows:
    sheet.row(row_id)
```

But how to get content of row (`xlwt.Row.Row` type)?

Comment: what is your goal? reading exel or writing?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434227/how-to-with-open-xlsx-file-with-python-3/37434349#37434349

Comment: @Rahul I need to get row of sheet as numpy array after it filled but before it saved to disk.